# Бот отвечает на собственные сообщения

Tags: telegram, aiogram, бот, asyncio

Пишу бота для техподдержки.Когда я отправляю вопрос, бот пересылает его на канал и начинает пересылать его тоже. И так продолжается бесконечно.

Пример(User- пользователь, который отправил боту вопрос, Bot1- бот, который отвечает пользователю, Bot2- бот, который пишет в канал)

P.S. Bot1 и Bot2 - один и тот же бот, написано для облегчения понимания.

- **Пользователь:** /start
- **Бот1**: Привет! Я бот технической поддержки. Опишите вашу проблему, и я передам ее операторам.
- **Пользователь**: *описывает свою проблему*
- **Бот1**: *отвечает на сообщение* Сообщение было передано операторам.
  Ожидайте ответа.
- **Бот2:** Отправляет сообщение на канал
- **Оператор:** *В комментариях к сообщению отвечает*
- **Бот2:** Пожалуйста, используйте команду /start для начала общения.

  ```
   bot = Bot(token='TOKEN')
   dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())
   nlp = spacy.load('ru_core_news_lg')
   conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
   db = conn.cursor()

   class States(StatesGroup):
       QUESTION = 'question'
       ANSWER = 'answer'
       FEEDBACK = 'feedback'

   @dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
   async def start_command(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
       await state.finish()  
       await state.update_data(question=message.text)  
       await send_to_operators(message.chat.id, state)

   @dp.message_handler()
   async def handle_message(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
       if message.text.lower() == 'завершить диалог':
           data = await state.get_data()
           question = data.get('question')
           answer = message.text
           save_to_database(question, answer)

           await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Диалог завершен. Если у вас возникнут еще вопросы, не стесняйтесь обращаться.")
           await state.finish()  
       else:
           await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Пожалуйста, используйте команду /start для начала общения.")

   def find_answer(question):
       question_doc = nlp(question)
       best_match = None
       best_score = 0.0
       for row in db:
           answer_doc = nlp(row['answer'])
           score = question_doc.similarity(answer_doc)
           if score > best_score:
               best_match = row['answer']
               best_score = score
       return best_match

   async def send_answer(chat_id, answer):
       keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
       keyboard.add(types.KeyboardButton('Да'), types.KeyboardButton('Нет'))
       await bot.send_message(chat_id, answer, reply_markup=keyboard)

   async def send_to_operators(question, state: FSMContext):
       channel_id = 'ID'
       data = await state.get_data()
       question = data.get('question')
       await bot.send_message(channel_id, f"Новый вопрос от пользователя:\n\n{question}")

   @dp.channel_post_handler(content_types=[types.ContentType.TEXT])
   async def handle_operator_reply(message: types.Message):
       if message.reply_to_message:
           user_question = message.reply_to_message.text  
           operator_reply = message.text  
           user_id = message.reply_to_message.from_user.id  
           await bot.send_message(user_id, operator_reply)

   def save_to_database(question, answer):
       db.execute("INSERT INTO question_answer (question, answer) VALUES (?, ?)", (question, answer))
       conn.commit()

   @dp.message_handler(state=States.QUESTION)
   async def handle_question(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
       question = message.text
       doc = nlp(question)
       processed_question = ' '.join([token.lemma_ for token in doc])

       answer = find_answer(processed_question)

       if answer != None:
           await send_answer(message.chat.id, answer)
           await state.update_data(question=question)
           await States.ANSWER.set()

       else:
           await send_to_operators(message.text)
           await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ваш вопрос передан операторам. Пожалуйста, ожидайте ответа.")
           data = await state.get_data()
           question = data.get('question')
           answer = message.text
           save_to_database(question, answer)

           await state.finish()
   @dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.TEXT, state=States.ANSWER)
   async def handle_feedback(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
       if message.text.lower() == 'да':
           await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Спасибо! Всего доброго.")
           await state.finish()  # Завершение состояния
       elif message.text.lower() == 'нет':
           # Отправляем вопрос операторам
           await send_to_operators(message.text)
           await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ваш вопрос передан операторам. Пожалуйста, ожидайте ответа.")
           data = await state.get_data()
           question = data.get('question')
           answer = message.text
           save_to_database(question, answer)

           await state.finish() 
       elif message.text.lower() == 'завершить диалог':
           data = await state.get_data()
           question = data.get('question')
           answer = message.text
           save_to_database(question, answer)

           await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Диалог завершен. Если у вас возникнут еще вопросы, не стесняйтесь обращаться.")
           await state.finish()
       else:
           await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Пожалуйста, используйте кнопки для ответа.")

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
       asyncio.run(dp.start_polling())
  ```